# Specfying lease time in DHCP request packet

Tags: python, networking, scapy, dhcp

I am trying to create a Dhcp request packet using scapy. Is there any way in which I can specify DHCP lease time in my request packet?

Comment: You can request a lease time using the correct DHCP option.

Comment: You can put option #51 in the request packet. I don't know if the server will use it, though.

Answer (score 1):

Put option #51, with the desired lease time as its value, in the `options` section of the `DHCPREQUEST` or `DHCPDISCOVER` packet.

From [RFC 2131 Section 3.5](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/2131/16.htm):

> In addition, the client may suggest values for the network address and lease time in the DHCPDISCOVER message. The client may include the 'requested IP address' option to suggest that a particular IP address be assigned, and may include the 'IP address lease time' option to suggest the lease time it would like.